# How do I use a library, installed with composer, that doesn't support autoloading?

Tags: php, laravel

How do I use a [library](https://github.com/mexitek/phpColors) installed with composer that doesn't support autoloading? E.g:

```
<?php

class ColorGenerator
{
    public function foo()
    {
        $color = new Color("#336699");
        //Class 'Color' not found

        $color = new phpColors\Color("#336699");
        //Class 'phpColors\Color' not found
    }
}
```

I presume need to require the class file, but I don't know what the best practice solution is.

Comment: For this simple one file, one class library you can write autoloader yourself. But if it's used in just this one class, don't bother, use `require_once`.

Comment: Aren't you missing `new` keyword?

Comment: Well actually that package *does* support autoloading (see [here](https://github.com/mexitek/phpColors/blob/master/composer.json#L14), it's just that it is only available in master and none of the tagged versions. Switch your dependency to `dev-master` and you should be fine. The fact that a new version hasn't been tagged since the autoload support was added 2 years ago suggests it's a pretty stagnant package, so my suggestion would be to either find a better one or deal with using `dev-master` from the looks of it.

Answer (score 0):

From the link you put:

```
/**
 * Using The Class
 */

use phpColors\Color;

// Initialize my color
$myBlue = new Color("#336699");

echo $myBlue->darken();
// 1a334d
```

That first line of code looks like something you may be interested in... Just make sure you have the source (phpColors folder) in the same directory as the .php file you are trying to use it in.

**EDIT:** Changed `using` to `use`. Thanks Rahil for catching that.

Comment: I think this is more a file require issue than a namespace issue - I get: Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
syntax error, unexpected 'phpColors' (T_STRING)

Comment: @MMacdonald The problem is there is no keyword `using` in PHP. Try `use`

Comment: Check @Marek's comment, use `require_once` if you're having issues or don't care about separate namespacing or autoloading. That may resolve the issue.